# How to make a screen contains google MapView and ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-mapview

I don't know how to create an custom Activity extending MapActivity and ListActivity ?
I am trying screen that contains of google map and list view.

How to make it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MapActivity you can add a listview resource. but you cant extend both activity. because java doesnt support multiple inheritence like you question.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me link or sample example about how to create a listview resource ?